# "You need to format your disk before you can use it" when hard disk is plugged in

Tags: hard-drive, format

When I plug in my hard disk it says, "you need to format your disk before you can use it" but when I click format, it says "Windows could not finish the format" that means my hard disk spoil?  I can't use my hard disk anymore?

Any solution to solve it so I could use the disk again?

Comment: Is it just one drive, or does it report this with other drives as well?  Does it do the same thing on another computer?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running check disk on the hard drive? scan it for errors and attempt to fix bad sectors - im assuming its a removable external hard drive. Run check disk , if all else shows up then have a look in Disk managment to see if the drive is being picked up (you can give it a drive letter here) and then try running a format through that.